# Sort users by registration date / time in WordPress by default

Tags: wordpress, sorting

How to sort the users by registration date in WordPress by default?
your-website/wp-admin/users.php shows users alphabetically by default.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'change_users_search_order' );
function change_users_search_order($obj){
if( !in_array($_REQUEST['order'],array('asc','desc')) ){
$_REQUEST['order'] = 'desc';
   }
$obj->query_orderby = "ORDER BY user_registered ".$_REQUEST['order']."";
   }
}
```